# Chebyshev nodes in Haskell

Tags: matlab, haskell, math

I want to use Haskell to compute the `n` Chebyshev nodes between `a` and `b`, which are given by the formula

`x_i = 0.5*((b+a) + (b-a)*cos((2*i-1)*pi)/(2*n))` where `i` goes from `1` to `n`.

I have so far focused on the cosine bit and came up with:

```
map (b-a)/(2*n)*cos (map (*pi) (map (-1) (map (*2) [1..n])))
```

However, this seems to me too convoluted and tedious given that my first motivation to learn this language is that it is portrayed to be mathematically friendly and so on.

Is my approach fundamentally wrong and there may be ways to make my code much more smarter and neater?

In matlab I would accomplish this with just two lines like this:

```
k = (1:n)';
x = 0.5*((b+a) + (b-a)*cos(((2*k-1)*pi)./(2*n)));
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define the terms as usual

```
cheb a b n k = 0.5*(b+a) + 0.5*(b-a)*cos( (2*k-1)*pi / (2*n) )
```

and define the function as

```
chebfun a b n = map (cheb a b n) [1..n]
```

this will give a list of n terms, evaluation is just summing it up.

Answer (score 1):

Use a list comprehension.

```
[ 0.5*((b+a) + (b-a)*cos((2*i-1)*pi/(2*n))) | i <- [1..n] ]
```

(I fixed an error in your parenthesization.)